# Filter Options using JSON API to Powershell - Currently using Invoke-Restmethd

Tags: json, powershell, rest, api

Just want to ask if anyone can help convert this to powershell? I believe this is Python. I am trying since yesterday and couldnt get the exact output.

Below Codes is in Pyhton and I cant convert it on powershell. I tried searching ways on how to filter things using Restmethod, JSON API to powershell but I cant make it work.

```
url = "https://test/"
input_data = '{"list_info":{"row_count":999,"start_index":1,"sort_field":"created_time","sort_order":"desc","get_total_count":true,"search_fields":{"subject":"ALERT"},"filter_by":{"name":"35704_MyView"},"fields_required":["subject","created_time"]}}'
params = {
    "TECHNICIAN_KEY": "ABCD-EDFC-QMFDJVA-PAOMD",
    "OPERATION_NAME": "read",
    "input_data": input_data
} 


response = requests.get(url, params=params, verify=False)
resp_json = response.json()
```

Basically I need to connect using restmethod and filter those highlighted in yellow using powershell.

Thanks!

[image: Need to filter these options]

Comment: Up. Up. Up. Up. Up.

Comment: This isn't dependent on the code but the API interface. What does the API documentation show is required for filtering?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the Python is just taking a hash of params and building a querystring for you.

You could do this with some string interpolation in PowerShell.

```
$url = "https://test/"
$input_data = '{"list_info":{"row_count":999,"start_index":1,"sort_field":"created_time","sort_order":"desc","get_total_count":true,"search_fields":{"subject":"ALERT"},"filter_by":{"name":"35704_MyView"},"fields_required":["subject","created_time"]}}'
$technician_key = "ABCD-EDFC-QMFDJVA-PAOMD"

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "$url`?TECHNICIAN_KEY=$technician_key&OPERATION_NAME=read&input_data=$input_data"
```

The Uri will end up looking like this:

```
https://test/?TECHNICIAN_KEY=ABCD-EDFC-QMFDJVA-PAOMD&OPERATION_NAME=read&input_data={"list_info":{"row_count":999,"start_index":1,"sort_field":"created_time","sort_order":"desc","get_total_count":true,"search_fields":{"subject":"ALERT"},"filter_by":{"name":"35704_MyView"},"fields_required":["subject","created_time"]}}
```

The backtick (`) in the string after `$url` tells the PowerShell parser that the question mark (?) is not part of the variable name.

There are some other ways to do this and I can't test this myself so some adjustments may be required for the service you're working with. As for the format of the `input_data` string, I can only guess. Hopefully, you can tweak as needed.